# Mailx doesn't send mail

Tags: linux, email, mailx

I'm having issues sending mail on a Debian (Lenny) box using mailx.

```
root@deity:/# mail root
Subject: Hai
Hi, root!
.
Cc:
```

-

```
root@deity:/# mail
No mail for root
```

Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

The following depends on your installed [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_transfer_agent), but because of security implications, mail is usually not delivered to root. You need to set up root as a mail alias to one of your "normal" users and read root's mail in that mailbox.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, hlovdal, but I'm afraid this is not the issue; I can't send mail to any of the users on the machine. My MTA is postfix.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was due to sendmail already running on port 25. I'm not sure why; it was removed prior to installing postfix.